# Apache or PHP not specifying the assets folder correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver, phalcon

I have this site written in PHP using Phalcon but for some reason when I switch from WAMP to XAMPP it doesn't use the public folder for assets like css/js/fonts/etc but uses the root folder instead? I've tried messing with the .htaccess files but no luck. Here's what I have:

.htaccess file in root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess file in root/public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Is there any way to fix it to make it get the assets from the public folder instead of the root folder?

Comment: How _exactly_ do the references look like in the html code you hand out to the clients? Relative paths? Or absolute paths? Or URLs?

Comment: And are you sure that those rewriting rules to get applied _at all_ ? How did you configure your http server so that you expect such distributed configuration files to be considered at all? How did you test that actually is the case?

Comment: They are referenced like this:

{{ stylesheet_link("css/materialize.min.css") }}
{{ javascript_include("js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js") }}

Comment: Weird thing is that the same code works just fine when I do it through WAMP with a virtual host.

Comment: Is there any way to confirm those rewrite rules are getting applied? @arkascha

Comment: `{{ stylesheet_link("css/materialize.min.css") }}` is only the internal notation in your template. What I asked for is how those references are actually expressed in the html code you hand out. You can easily check that in your browser, just look at the code of your page in there.

Comment: To debug you have to steps: first make sure your distributed configuration file gets applied at all. For that place a definite syntax error inside and monitor your http server's error log file while restarting it and making a request. Do you see that syntax error in that log file? That would prove that the file gets considered. The next step is to enable rewrite logging. You should take a look into the documentation of the tools you are using for that, here that would be the documentation of the apache http server's rewrite module.

Comment: And certainly your two different http server environments can be configured different, that is not surprosing. I would certainly not consider that a weird thing, since there is no right or wrong configuration and different distributions of a software certainly can use different default configurations.

Comment: Here's how it looks for the user on a browser: @arkascha
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/materialize.min.css" />`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: OK, so you generate absolute paths as references. This would explain the effect if you operate you application in different "folders" inside your two different http server environments. If not, so if in both cases the application is located in the top level of the http server's name spaces, then this does not make any difference. You will need to start debugging as I mentioned before.